# How to query a datatable in C#

Tags: linq, datatable, console-application

I have a datatable with a number of columns. Two of them are `JobNum` and `ProcessNum`. I want to see if I have duplicate records in the datatable.

Normally in SQL I would just do a

```
select count(jobnum) cntjobnum, JobNum, ProcessNum 
from table 
where jobnum = '1234' and processnum = '5678'
```

Is there a similar manner in C# (using a C# console app)?

Comment: I do not have a DBSet the datatable is being populated from a CSV file. form CSVUtility

Comment: oh and group by jobnum, processnum

Answer (score 0):

> I want to see if I have duplicate records in the datatable.

I don't think that your SQL statement will detect duplicate records, do you?

There is no LINQ method to detect **if** there are duplicates in an `IEnumerable<...>`. However, there are methods to detect the duplicates. If you only want to find whether there are duplicates or not, if is not very efficient to continue processing the other elements after you have found a duplicate. So the most efficient method would be to stop as soon as you have found a duplicate.

```
public static bool HasDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return HasDuplicates(source, null);
}

public static bool HasDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(...);

    // if null comparer, use the default comparer:
    if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
    foreach (T t in source)
    {
        if (set.Contains(t))
            return true; // found a duplicate
        else
            set.Add(t);
    }
    return false; // no duplicates found
}
```

If you want to find all duplicates, consider to use `GroupBy`, and use the complete item as key.

```
IEnumerable<Product> products = ...
IEqualityComparer<Product> comparer = ... // or use default comparison

var duplicates = products.GroupBy(product => product, comparer)

    // keep only the groups that have more than one element
    .Where(group => group.Skip(1).Any())

    // from the remaining groups, take the key (which is the product
    .Select(group => group.Key);
    (key, elementsWithThisKey) =>
```